# Are the requirements for attaining godhood in LDS teaching the same or different for every world?

Tags: soteriology, lds, afterlife

In my understanding of LDS teaching, both Jesus and Lucifer proposed plans of salvation to Elohim, and Jesus' plan was chosen.  As a result, some people on earth may attain godhood if they follow the gospel and obey its teachings to a high enough standard.

The idea that two plans of salvation were offered seems to indicate that there really was an option.  So, my question is whether or not the attainment of godhood is the same for all worlds or if the requirements could be vastly different from world to world.  Does each god have the option of creating his own requirements for his spiritual children to attain godhood themselves or is there, in reality, one universal gospel for all worlds and all gods?

Comment: Again, with most of your questions like this, the answer is: "We don't know" or "It hasn't been revealed."

Comment: Perhaps there are both Calvinistic and Arminianist gods in the LDS universe!

Comment: @Matt Well, I can't know it hasn't been revealed until I ask.  :)  So, I might as well ask...  I am definitely curious as I ponder these things.

Comment: @curiousdannii OH NO!  I can see a new sect arising out of your comment... perhaps the divide between Armenianism and Calvinism could be explained by suggesting there are two gods whose spiritual children populate this world--one of whom is Calvinist, and the other of whom is Armenian.  So, both the Calvinist AND the Armenian is correct--they are just on two different systems!

Comment: @Narnian It certainly doesn't hurt to ask, but perhaps understanding a more general fact about LDS doctrine will help you arrive at your own conclusion (teach the man how to fish, not just give him a fish, kind of thing): [the account of Gods and worlds are not revealed to us here](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/moses/1.35?lang=eng#34).

Comment: @Matt Interesting.  I don't think I have ever seen that.  So, there is some that is revealed, but perhaps much that is hidden.  I would suggest, though, that perhaps we can something about the answer to this question, because we do know that two options were proposed for this world.  I'm wondering if there is any LDS teaching on this as a result.

Comment: No time to give a proper answer, but the first section of this: [Gospel Principles: Jesus Christ, Our Chosen Leader and Savior](http://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-3-jesus-christ-our-chosen-leader-and-savior?lang=eng) certainly covers the idea of multiple plans. Spoiler: the 2nd plan wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @Narnian: Matt's right on this one. Many of your recent questions on topics related to this one are things that have not been revealed because, as interesting of intellectual curiosities as they may make for, they aren't actually relevant to our salvation.  And I keep being reminded of a certain verse from [Jacob chapter 4](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/jacob/4) in the Book of Mormon.  It's verse 14, but read the whole chapter for context.  It essentially says that focusing overly much on mysteries rather than important Gospel principles can be a trap that ends up getting you lost.

Comment: As @tom points out, there was God's plan (and Jesus agreed to be the Savior in that plan), and then Satan proposed his plan (which wouldn't have worked, and wanted God's glory in payment for a bad plan).

Answer (score 3):

The plan was put forth by Elohim and when it was understood that a Redeemer was needed to effect the plan it was then that his Beloved and First born Son responded, "Here am I, send me"...

There never was an option.

- ["Come, Know the Lord Jesus"  McConkie, General Conference, April 1977](http://www.lds.org/general-conference/1977/04/come-know-the-lord-jesus?lang=eng)

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you could add references. Also, as a new visitor I'd recommend the following links to help dispel any misconceptions you may have about what this site is and what it isn't.  [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You're kinda asking two questions.  One is in your title: could other worlds have a different plan?  The other is in the question: was there an option for our world?

The answer to the second question is "no," as was explained by @Tom.

The best answer we can give you to the first question is, "apparently."  Please keep in mind that the answer doesn't matter — the rules for us apply to us and whether or not they apply to anyone else doesn't matter at all.  Conversely, the rules for others apply to others and don't apply to us at all.  Knowing that, we have two evidences that suggest other Plans of Salvation *could* be different.  The first comes from scripture:

> All truth is independent in that sphere in which God has placed it, to act for itself, as all intelligence also; otherwise there is no existence. ([D&C 93:30](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/93.30?lang=eng#29))

The second comes from our Temple services.  Please forgive me for not quoting the service, we believe it to be our most sacred, but what it teaches is that when Satan tempted Eve, he was acting in a way he had known used on other worlds.

So, does what I said prove a belief that other worlds may and/or do have other plans? No, it actually doesn't. It only suggests a possibility.<sup>1</sup>  And officially, the Church has no doctrinal or dogmatic statement on the subject because, as I said earlier, it doesn't actually matter.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *The two sources I cite and verses from the Books of Abraham and Moses have been used by some over the decades to speculate a great many things.  Perhaps the most peculiar is that Jesus died for people on other worlds.  But they have also used these verses to speculate both that other worlds had the same Plan and other worlds had different Plans. It's all speculation — and considering how precious little the Lord has revealed about what may or may not go on with other creations of our Heavenly Father, it's wild-and-crazy speculation indeed. It should go without saying that absolutely none of it represents Church doctrine or dogma.*</sub>